# What is an easier method of moving widgets on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, interactive

The methods of moving widgets around on a canvas seem time consuming. Is there an easier way to arrange wigets (ie arranging them through some additional app that uses absolute geometry and allows you to move stretch etc widget which just changes the co-ordinates of its value)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you wanting to be able to move widgets around (possibly with the mouse?) while your app is running, are you asking about a tool that lets you visually layout widgets during development, or are you just asking about how to arrange widgets in your app?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into the `.grid(row = <>, column = <>, rowspan = <>, columnspan = <>)` method that can be called on every tkinter widget?